# Parse a date string into a date already part of an object in JavaScript? (code included)

Tags: javascript, date, parsing

I'm wondering how I can parse this date string in `object.modified` in JavaScript into date format. If I have this code:

```
var object = {
    "path" : "C:/Users/exampleuser/Desktop/test/testfile.txt",
    "modified" : "24-10-2019"
};
```

I've tried using `Date.parse()` but no luck so far.

Comment: have a look at `moment' js

Answer (score -1):

```
var object = {
    "path" : "C:/Users/exampleuser/Desktop/test/testfile.txt",
    "modified" : "24-10-2019"
};

var objectParse = Date(object.modified)

console.log(objectParse)
```

Comment: `new Date("24-10-2019")` produces an invalid date in Safari, Chrome and Firefox at least. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a date object and pass the value of object.modified in that

```
var object = {
    "path" : "C:/Users/exampleuser/Desktop/test/testfile.txt",
    "modified" : "24-10-2019"
};
var date = Date(object.modified)
console.log(date)
```

Output will be :
Thu Oct 24 2019 14:29:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: `new Date("24-10-2019")` produces an invalid date in Safari, Chrome and Firefox at least. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)